# Sequelize conditional model include

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have this models:

user

- id
- user_type_id
- ...

user_types

- id
- name (type_1, type_2)

type_1

- id
- fields for type_1

type_2

- id
- fields for type_2

What i need is something like this

```
const users = await user.findOne({
    where: {
        [Op.and]: { email }
    },
    // Conditional include if user_type_id on user model is 1 I need bring type_1 fields otherwise type_2
    include: [
        {
           ??
        }
    ]
})
```

Thank You in advance

Comment: I don't think there's going to be a way to do it the way you want. I can think of a a couple of options. One would be to just always include both type_1 and type_2 and then add some methods to your user class that make it easy to get the field value you want. The other way would be to not include these associations i n the query, and then add some methods to your User class to pull in those fields based on the user.name.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @PeterHaight